# Comparison of signature algorithms HMACSHA1 and RSASHA1

Tags: digital-signature, integrity

Compare and contrast the signature algorithms HMACSHA1 and RSASHA1.

Assume that the aim here is to make it infeasible to generate valid message+sig pairs without knowing a certain private token/key (but of course, not sending said key over the wire, even though both parties are trusted).

Would there be a reason to choose one method over the other? I would probably prefer public-key-based RSASHA1, but is that necessary, or even advantageous?

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework question, which isn't prohibited, but would get better answers if phrased "Is my understanding of these differences between X and Y correct", with points of difference that you've researched included in the question.

Comment: @Matthew only homework in the sense that I'm trying to do my homework before picking a signature algorithm to use in production :).  But OK, I'll research some more and put in anything useful if I find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HMAC-SHA1 is a message authentication code (MAC) algorithm, RSA-SHA1 is a signature algorithm. Though MACs are sometimes incorrectly called signatures, they are fundamentally different.

With a MAC, anyone knowing the secret key can both create and verify MACs. With signatures on the other hand, anyone with the public key can verify a signature, but only someone with the private key can create a signature.

Signatures are used when it is desired that the party verifying the signature not be able to create signatures. PGP uses them to verify message authorship, TLS use them to verify certificate chains.

MACs are used when all parties involved simply want to know that the message came unaltered from another valid party. TLS uses them to verify that messages are unaltered between the client and server.

MACs are generally significantly faster than signatures. A signature where both parties know the public and private keys could be used as a MAC, but performance would be much worse.

Note that SHA1 is being deprecated in most places due to [collision attack](http://shattered.io). The collision attack [doesn't affect HMAC-SHA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26518), but it may be desirable to use HMAC-SHA256 instead if only to avoid unneeded questions. SHA1 *should* be avoided with RSA signatures if the attacker has any control over what you're signing, and since it may not always be clear whether or not this is the case (or could be the case in the future due to changes), it's best to just use SHA256.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Since all I need is a message authentication code, I'll go with HMACSHA1.

Comment: @NH. Note that SHA1 is being deprecated as it is vulnerable to collisions. This doesn't actually affect its use with HMAC at all, but it may be desirable to go with HMAC-SH256 if only to avoid people asking questions.

Comment: @AG so I see: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27530/51938

Comment: Even without the attacks culminating in 'shattered', SHA1 was/is deprecated for its maximum 80-bit collision strength. NIST officially prohibited it for many applications including signature, along with 1024-bit 'factorization' (RSA) and 'finite-field' (DSA, DH), starting in 2014 for their jurisdiction (basically US federal government less military/intelligence), and web CAs stopped issuing and major browsers started warning for or rejecting SHA1 certs over 2015-2016 -- see many Qs from that period -- but HMAC-SHA1 isn't hurt by collision and is still okay.